# Gradle use a class from sources as part of the package phase

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am using this with Android, but I think it can apply to any gradle project.

I have some files I want packaged in the final archive.
I want this files to be encrypted, and then the app will decrypt them when reading.

What I use:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    dexDebug.dependsOn(encryptFiles)
}

task encryptFiles<< {
....
}
```

I want in encryptFiles to use the helper class from the sources., like this:

```
decryptedDir.eachFileMatch(p) { File f -> EncryptHelper.encrypt(f, destination) }
```

How can I setup the classpath for my task (encryptFiles) so I can use the classpath at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extract encryption and decryption code into separate jar library, independent from the Android project. After doing so, I would use it as a dependency in Gradle build scripts and Android application. It would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: indeed, that is a good idea and it works. However, my encryption is a single class and managing an independent project just for it seems overkill to me. I have just copied the encrypt code in build.gradle until I find a better way. Just as a note, I have tried extracting the code in a module inside the android project project, but that did not work, also, if set as a build classpath dependency, the build would lock the jar and clean would fail.